# Transfer regex from Java to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How can I transfer the following regex from Java to PostgreSQL syntax:

```
Pattern.compile("(?imu)(P\\W*Ř\\W*E\\W*D\\W*V\\W*O\\W*L\\W*Á\\W*N\\W*Í)"));
```

I have tried:

```
select regexp_matches('P Ř E D V O L Á N Í','(?imu)(P\\W*Ř\\W*E\\W*D\\W*V\\W*O\\W*L\\W*Á\\W*N\\W*Í)')
```

But got `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid embedded option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres uses POSIX RE's that don't support the `u` (Enable Unicode-aware case folding) flag in `(?imu)`

Comment: Thank you. I've ended up with `select regexp_matches(upper('PřED vo lÁn í'),'(P[[:space:]]*Ř[[:space:]]*E[[:space:]]*D[[:space:]]*V[[:space:]]*O[[:space:]]*L[[:space:]]*Á[[:space:]]*N[[:space:]]*Í)')` Not the same, but seems to work.